# Does RLlib `rollout.py` work for evaluation?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, ray, rllib

TL;DR: RLlib's `rollout` command seems to be training the network, not evaluating.

I'm trying to use Ray RLlib's DQN to train, save, and evaluate neural networks on a custom made simulator. To do so, I've been prototyping the workflow with OpenAI Gym's CartPole-v0 environment. Doing so, I found some odd results while running the `rollout` command for evaluation. (I used the exact same method written in [RLlib Training APIs - Evaluating Trained Policies documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/rllib-training.html#evaluating-trained-policies).)

First I trained a vanilla DQN network until it reached a `episode_reward_mean` of 200 points. Then, I used the `rllib rollout` command to test the network for 1000 episodes in CartPole-v0. For the first 135 episodes, the `episode_reward_mean` score was awful, ranging from 10 to 200. However, from the 136th episode, the score was consistently 200, which is full points in CartPole-v0.

So, it seems like `rllib rollout` is rather training the network, not evaluating. I know that isn't the case since there's no code for training in `rollout.py` module. But I have to say, it really looks like training. Otherwise, how can the score gradually increase as more episodes happen? Furthermore, the network is "adapting" to different starting positions later in the evaluation process, which is an evidence of training in my perspective.

Why this might be happening?

The code I used is below:

- Training

```py
results = tune.run(
                    "DQN",
                    stop={"episode_reward_mean": 200},
                    config={
                            "env": "CartPole-v0",
                            "num_workers": 6
                    },
                    checkpoint_freq=0,
                    keep_checkpoints_num=1,
                    checkpoint_score_attr="episode_reward_mean",
                    checkpoint_at_end=True,
                    local_dir=r"/home/ray_results/CartPole_Evaluation"
)
```

- Evaluation

```
rllib rollout ~/ray_results/CartPole_Evaluation/DQN_CartPole-v0_13hfd/checkpoint_139/checkpoint-139 \
             --run DQN --env CartPole-v0 --episodes 1000
```

- Result

```
2021-01-12 17:26:48,764 INFO trainable.py:489 -- Current state after restoring: {'_iteration': 77, '_timesteps_total': None, '_time_total': 128.41606998443604, '_episodes_total': 819}
Episode #0: reward: 21.0
Episode #1: reward: 13.0
Episode #2: reward: 13.0
Episode #3: reward: 27.0
Episode #4: reward: 26.0
Episode #5: reward: 14.0
Episode #6: reward: 16.0
Episode #7: reward: 22.0
Episode #8: reward: 25.0
Episode #9: reward: 17.0
Episode #10: reward: 16.0
Episode #11: reward: 31.0
Episode #12: reward: 10.0
Episode #13: reward: 23.0
Episode #14: reward: 17.0
Episode #15: reward: 41.0
Episode #16: reward: 46.0
Episode #17: reward: 15.0
Episode #18: reward: 17.0
Episode #19: reward: 32.0
Episode #20: reward: 25.0
...
Episode #114: reward: 134.0
Episode #115: reward: 90.0
Episode #116: reward: 38.0
Episode #117: reward: 33.0
Episode #118: reward: 36.0
Episode #119: reward: 114.0
Episode #120: reward: 183.0
Episode #121: reward: 200.0
Episode #122: reward: 166.0
Episode #123: reward: 200.0
Episode #124: reward: 155.0
Episode #125: reward: 181.0
Episode #126: reward: 72.0
Episode #127: reward: 200.0
Episode #128: reward: 54.0
Episode #129: reward: 196.0
Episode #130: reward: 200.0
Episode #131: reward: 200.0
Episode #132: reward: 188.0
Episode #133: reward: 200.0
Episode #134: reward: 200.0
Episode #135: reward: 173.0
Episode #136: reward: 200.0
Episode #137: reward: 200.0
Episode #138: reward: 200.0
Episode #139: reward: 200.0
Episode #140: reward: 200.0
...
Episode #988: reward: 200.0
Episode #989: reward: 200.0
Episode #990: reward: 200.0
Episode #991: reward: 200.0
Episode #992: reward: 200.0
Episode #993: reward: 200.0
Episode #994: reward: 200.0
Episode #995: reward: 200.0
Episode #996: reward: 200.0
Episode #997: reward: 200.0
Episode #998: reward: 200.0
Episode #999: reward: 200.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I posted the same question on [Ray Discussion](https://discuss.ray.io/t/rllib-rollout-command-seems-to-be-training-the-network-not-evaluating/485) and got an answer that fixes this issue.

Since I'm calling `rollout` on the trained network, which has `EpsilonGreedy` exploration module set for 10k steps, the agent is actually choosing actions with some randomness at first. However, as it undergoes more timesteps, the randomness part gets reduced to 0.02, making the network choosing only the best actions. This is why the restored agent seems to be training when called with `rollout`.

The solution to this problem, as suggested by Sven Mika, is to simply suppress the exploration behavior for evaluation:

```py
config:
     evaluation_config:
         explore: false
```

This resulted in the agent scoring 200 for al episodes tested!